# how to add new category in post page laravel

Tags: php, laravel

when i want to make a post i have to first create a category on a different page, namely the category page, not the post page. how to make it like wordpress which can add categories and tags on the post page.

i have tried but i don't know how to make validation so that the category name and category slug (Str::slug) are unique.

after I tried to successfully add a category on the post page but when I added an existing category it still worked, not unique.

[image: Same Category not unique]

PostController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name' => 'required',
        'categories' => 'required',
    ]);

    $slug = Str::slug($request->name);

    $post = new Post();
    $post->user_id = Auth::id();
    $post->name = $request->name;
    $post->slug = $slug;

    $post->save();

    // get old categories name
    $existingCategory = $video->categories->pluck('name')->toArray();

    // find new categories
    foreach($request->categories as $category) {
        if(! ( in_array($category, $existingCategory) ) ) {

            //create a new category
            $newCategory = new Category();
            $newCategory->name = $category;
            $newCategory->slug = Str::slug($category);
            $newCategory->save();
        }
    }

    $attachableCategory = [];

    foreach($request->categories as $category) {
        $attachableCategory[] = Category::where('name', $category)->pluck('id')->first();
    }

    $video->categories()->sync($attachableCategory);

    return redirect()->route('admin.post.index');
}
```

Comment: Inside the loop you are not providing slug for category.

Comment: @RAZIUL when i try add 'slug' => $slug in foreach still same error, i edit my code.

Answer (score 1):

It seem that your categories are an array. I they are. Problably your are looking for array validation

```
Validator::make($input, [
     // validates there is an array 
    'categories' => 'required|array|min:1',  
     
     // validates values inside array
    'categories.*' => 'required|string|min:4'
]);
```

Comment: check i edit my code, I have successfully added category in post, but category is not unique. when I add an existing category.

Comment: Do you mean that you want that a post have only one category? If so, your categories array validation should be 'categories' => 'required|array|1',  this require exactly one category

Comment: I want one post to have many categories and category name unique. look this https://prnt.sc/J8it78R0_IKA same name category

Comment: This should work. Validator::make($input, [
     // validates there is an array 
    'categories' => 'required|array|min:1',  
     
     // validates values inside array
    'categories.*' => 'required|unique:categories,name|distinct|string|min:4'
]);

Comment: im try to add validator in loop category and getting error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'test' for key 'posts_slug_unique'

Comment: The last result seems to be related to post saving. You should separate funtionalities saving categories from a categories controller and post from a post controller as you are making many things in the same controller and method, which is a bad practice.